# pyvisa-py PyUSB does not seem to be properly installed

Tags: pyusb, pyvisa

I am on windows 10, and this issue just recently popped up, I was not having this issue before today. I can run my program on a different computer by just installing pyvisa, pyvisa-py, pyusb. On my computer I get:

```
ValueError: PyUSB does not seem to be properly installed.
Please refer to PyUSB documentation and 
install a suitable backend like 
libusb 0.1, libusb 1.0, libusbx, 
libusb-win32 or OpenUSB.
No backend available
```

and when I try pyvisa-info I get the same thing:

```
USB INSTR:
         PyUSB does not seem to be properly installed.
         Please refer to PyUSB documentation and
         install a suitable backend like
         libusb 0.1, libusb 1.0, libusbx,
         libusb-win32 or OpenUSB.
         No backend available
```

I have tried putting libusb-1.0.dll in system32 and some other fixes I found but none of them worked. I don't want to use a different usb backend, since the program already works with pyusb and pyvisa-py. I am not sure what I did to make it not work on my computer recently.